# 2000s movie about testing LSD; people were forced to endlessly watch short video loops

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

In English

Woman was main character I believe

Human testing with LSD
The woman had many people in cryogenic tubes full of liquid hooked up to IVs and watching the same 5/10second clip over and over. Looped forever causing major psychological distress on the people.

I also remember at some point there being two separate realities.

Comment: Welcome to the Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information on this site and how it works. At this point, I don't see that this question is in the realm of science fiction - it could have been a documentary on "scientific" experimentation with LSD from the way it is worded. Actual science is off-topic here, but may be on-topic on other Stacks. There was a covert CIA operation called MKUltra that did things like this in the 1970's(?)

Comment: @FuzzyBoots "To me, the two separate realities could match" --could match what? Was there a deleted comment speculating on what this might be?

Comment: @Hypnosifl: Sorry. I was trying to say that if there were two different realities, then it sounds like an SF&F question.